# Print PCB on copper using Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication, gerber

I've been trying to print and make my own circuit using Altium (print it on film paper, iron it on copper-coated plastic and then dip it in Ferric Chloride etc.), using Gerber files. Only problem is, Gerber files don't show the holes (and obviously I can't print the drill file) and I can't print the PCB directly since that I can't separate the layers while printing the PCB. Any idea on how to print holes normally?

I've been looking for an answer for a long time but couldn't find anything that worked for me (looked mostly at [this](http://www.edaboard.com/thread160359.html)).

Comment: Export to DXF, maybe?

Comment: You can print separate layers from Altium.

Comment: You can afford access to Altium but you can't afford 10 bucks to have a prototyping shop fabricate actual PCBs for you?

Comment: Photon - how? I tried to make a pdf of the entire project but it doesn't separate the layers.
brhans - I know, but only after creating a gerber...
whatisname - I got the altium as a student...

Comment: @whatsisname arrr, the high seas calls ye matey! pirates ahoy!

Comment: @whatsisname also, this person could be a student, like I was once, with access to university paid Altium licenses, just no money in general for PCB (like most students :(  )

Comment: @whatsisname - please tell me where I can have a simple prototype PCB made in an hour or two for $10

Comment: I would like to know that cheap PCB manufacturer too...

Comment: @Triak http://www.pcbway.com/ $10 but not in 2 hours.....

Answer (score 5):

So you have got a drill file, in *txt* format. You can drag this *txt* and drop into the Altium Designer. You will get the following dialog:

[image]

Click OK and your drill file will be loaded like this:

[image]

Now, you can select \$ \textbf{File}  \longrightarrow  \textbf{Print}\$, set  **Print Scalling** to \$ \textbf{User Scale = 1.0}\$. The page orientation can be set under the **Printer Setup** option.

[image]

As a demonstration I have just printed it as a PDF document, here is the output on an A4 sheet:

[image]

- the board dimensions: **67.6mm x 149.25mm**
- the A4 sheet dimensions: **210mm x 297mm**

According to this: \$ \frac{297mm}{149.25mm} = 1.9899 \$, there must be enough space  along the height of the page for almost two printing.
It can be seen on the picture above that this condition is fulfilled(, if we place the printing at the edge of the sheet).

Consider it as a workaround, there could be much more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: Really helpful, thank you, but I've tried that and the problem is that it's not in the correct scale (I've tried save drill and then import drill in the gerber) - I get 80cm*80cm drills while pcb is 11cm*11cm

Comment: So if I understand, Altium generates the gerber and the drill file with different scale? When generating them did you select the same unit?

Comment: The print scale is 1:1? Maybe is "Fit to Document"

Answer (score 2):

You have not stated how many layers you use, but I suppose that you use 2 layers. Top and bottom.

It is actually pretty easy to print the PCB on paper, through printer. You do not have to use Gerber files to output the PCB, but use print option and select printer to print on.

Here is an example, we will print top layer 1st, then bottom layer.>

1. Open the PCB which needs to be printed.
2. File>Page Setup... (Composite Properties window should pop up)
3. On the Composite Properties set your paper and quality setting, also set these>

   - scale mode = Scaled Print
   - scale = 1.00
   - corrections x = y = 1.00
   - color set Mono
   - if you experiment with offset settings you can get both layers on one paper(!)
     [image]
4. Go to Advanced...
5. Delete all layers except top and multi layer (right click>delete)
   [image]
6. Check holes and mirror (because top needs to be mirrored) > OK
7. File > Print Preview... - make sure it looks like it need to be, all holes should be there (if not, reset Altium Designer)
8. Print... > select your printer settings and print to the paper.
9. We finished top layer. To print bottom layer, do all steps from 4 to 8, but make sure you add bottom layer (right click>insert), delete top layer and mirror is unchecked. 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Altium won't print the drill holes on it's output options as anything other than white, so if you want a negative you need to place a small dot in the center of each through hole pad on an unused layer, set it to print that layer in black and move it to the topmost print.